# How to dinamically access to a field in django form to change instance

Tags: django, forms

Using a generic CreateView in Django I'm trying to save only the fields that have been changed by user.

I'm trying to do this in my view:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.has_changed():
          
          for field in form:
           

            if field.name in form.changed_data:
            
                continue
                
            else:
               
                form.instance.field=None
```

In the last line I got this error:

object has no attribute 'field'

Is there a way to dynamically access to each field in the form? so I could change it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to dynamically access to each field in the form.
Yes.

```
form.fields[field_name]
```

So I could change it?
Yes.

```
form.fields[field_name] = django.forms.Charfield(required=False)
```

But in your code, probably you want to achieve value of the field:

```
field_value = form[field_name].value
```

If you have a data bounded field, you can change also data of form:

```
form.data(form.add_prefix(field_name)) = new_value
```

But this is already wrong approach to change something here.

I can imagine: in your case you don't understand how form / modelform saves the data and therefore you want to do something unnecessary:

Once more time, how `ModelForm` "saves" the data in DB:

1. Form validate the data.
2. Form clean the data.
3. on form.save(**kwargs) - Form create the instance and:

- call instance.save() if form.save(commit=True)
- dont call instance.save() if form.save(commit=False)

4. Instance saves the data.

Form don't save anything itself, `instance.save` - There is all what you need.

```
instance.save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None)
```

In your case you use CreateView - there all fields should be initiated, you can not UPDATE something, this something not exists yet. You can only avoid empty values, if you  want.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.has_changed():
        form.cleaned_data = {key:val for key,val in form.cleaned_data.items() if val and key in form.changed_data}
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

al last: `form.instance.field` is ridiculous

- `form` has fields. You can achieve every `field` by name.
- `Model class` has fields. You can achieve every `field` by name.
- `instance` has attributes or properties. You can achieve every `attribute` by name.

And right now: what you are really want to do?

Comment: Thanks @maxim-danilov . What I'm trying to do is to save only the modified fields, not those which only content the initial data.

Comment: I have tried this: def form_valid(self, form): if form.has_changed(): form.changed_data = {key:val for key,val in form.changed_data.items() if val} return super().form_valid(form)     But  I get this error:    'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Sorry. I mean cleaned_data, and not changed_data. Cleaned_data is dict, changed_data is list. I change the answer.

Comment: Thanks @maxim-danilov. Now if I do print(form.cleaned_data) it only prints the modified fields, but form_valid keeps saving also the other fields even when they where not modified. I do not understand why.

Comment: if it is a new object  all fields should be saved.

Comment: Is there a way to set the other fields to None? Something like:    form.cleaned_data = {key:val for key,val in form.cleaned_data.items() if val and key in form.changed_data else key:None}  I know this way doesn't work, but , is there a way to do it?

Comment: thanks @maxim-danilov. I tried this:  dicchanged = {key:val for key,val in form.cleaned_data.items() if val and key in form.changed_data}  dicnotchanged= {key:None for key,val in form.cleaned_data.items() if key not in form.changed_data}        and then:     diccleaned=dicchanged    diccleaned.update(dicnotchanged)    diccleaned['prueba'] = prueba   #a foreign field which shouldn't be changed,   then   I did this:   form.cleaned_data= diccleaned    and if I do print (form.cleaned_data) everything seems to be ok. But when I return form.is_valid(form) it saves the form as it was before.